# How can I auto push blog post or markdown file to bitbucket?

Tags: markdown, jekyll

I am a blogger and a new user for Jekyll. Everything is okay when viewed from the outside. But I think pushing a post to the cloud by opening the  console is ridiculous. I migrated from Wordpress to Jekyll because of simplicity. I like it.

I just want to write blog and save my article to the markdown file. It must auto push the post, which is a Markdown (.md) file.

Is there anything I can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Bitbucket is the place you want to host your blog, then [Bitbucket has a way to publish static websites to their cloud](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/publishing-a-website-on-bitbucket-cloud-221449776.html), **however**, the website will have a `.bitbucket.org` domain affixed to them by default.

If you prefer to use Jekyll on GitHub pages, in fact [here is a tutorial](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/08/build-blog-jekyll-github-pages/) that tries to make sure you don't do anything locally with Git, so you can just publish using the GitHub online editor and Markdown. If you're up for something more customized though, [here is a good guide on how to do that](http://jmcglone.com/guides/github-pages/), with minimal use of the command line.

Judging by your question I would suggest the GitHub Pages way is the way to go, as you do it all with little or no local install of Jekyll and Git from the command line, saving a file will automatically publish as well.

There's also [Dillinger](http://dillinger.io/), a very pretty Markdown editor, which seems like something you would want.

**EDIT** after the user emailed me personally.

The whole point of Jekyll is for people who use the command line and want Git as a version control system.

You seem to be leaning towards Blogger and Wordpress, why not just stick to those then? That way you don't need to use the command line.

If you just want to focus on writing, stay with those websites, they work great. Static sites are mean for those who don't mind using the terminal a lot and want unlimited customization abilities. There's also [ghost.org](http://ghost.org), which I think does static sites and doesn't require a terminal, they charge a fee I think.

There's nothing wrong with a public repo, as stuff you write will already be on the internet anyway, it's the same as view source on a webpage. If you use your own domain name and don't provide a link to the public repo (which again will just be your website stuff, which is already online), people won't really go hunt for it.

Go back to a simple blogging platform if you don't want to cope with details. I think it's good you considered your options, but Jekyll isn't good for everyone.